# WordPress AJAX return 0 - My case

Tags: ajax, jquery

My problem is the same as in other cases, but my code is fine, I compared with another and followed all the instructions and good practices, but it does not work. Here my code:

```
jQuery("#genera-pdf").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var price1 = jQuery('input[type=text][id=price1]').val();
  var price2 = jQuery('input[type=text][id=price2]').val();

   jQuery.ajax({
               url : '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
               type: 'POST',
               data: {action: 'pdfAction', a: price1, b: price2}),
               success: function(data){
                   alert(data);     
               },
               error: function(errorThrown){
                   alert(errorThrown);
               }
             });
          });
```

And my function is:

```
function pdfAction(){
$post = $_POST['pdfAction'];
echo "something";

wp_die();

}
add_action('wp_ajax_pdfAction','pdfAction_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_pdfAction','pdfAction_callback');
```

Any idea that is happening?

Comment: Have you tried using the REST API for ajax instead? It's a much better API and actually tells you what the problem is in plain english, rather than returning `0` with no explanation

Comment: Please, how I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You function name and your ajax action callback name should be same.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_pdfAction','pdfAction_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_pdfAction','pdfAction_callback');

function pdfAction_callback(){
    $post = $_POST['pdfAction'];
    echo "something";

    wp_die();

}
```

Please update your php code with the above.

Currently, your php function is not getting executed.

**Update:**

The Ajax Script,

```
$(document).on('click', "#generate-pdf", function(){

    var price1 = $("#price1").val();
    var price2 = $("#price2").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: ajax_object.ajax_url, // AJAX handler
        data: {
            'action': 'pdfAction',
            'price_1': price1,
            'price_2': price2
        },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {

            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.price_1) // to access individual values

        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
    return false;

});
```

Register Ajax Action Url and Script,

```
function ajax_enqueue_scripts() {

    // Enqueue your javascript file 
    wp_register_script( 'ajax-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-scripts.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );

    // in JavaScript, object properties are accessed as ajax_object.ajax_url
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-scripts', 'ajax_object', array( 
        'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), // admin ajax url 
    ));

    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-scripts');

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Ajax Request Callback function,

```
add_action('wp_ajax_pdfAction','pdfAction_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_pdfAction','pdfAction_callback');

function pdfAction_callback(){

    // Getting data sent from Ajax request

    $price_1 = $_POST['price_1'];
    $price_2 = $_POST['price_2'];


    // Prepare Data to be send back to AJAX request
    $return = array(
        'price_1'  => $price_1,
        'price_2'  => $price_2
    );

    wp_send_json($return); // Send JSON response back to our AJAX Request and die().

    // we don't require wp_die(); here wp_send_json() will take care of it.

}
```

You also should consider using nonce here for security purpose.

Comment: I did but does not work.

Comment: As @MikeNGarrett stated your code has lots of errors, check my update in answer to learn how to use ajax properly in WordPress.

Comment: Thanks for improving upon my answer.

Comment: @DeepakSingh I applied the change in the code but it does not work, and an error is shown in the console `ajax_object is not defined`

Comment: @MirquezRodriguez  please  check my answer I have updated ajax_enqueue_scripts() function.

Comment: the same error in jQuery "ajax_object" is not defined. I am using theme options to write my jQuery code, is this a problem?

Comment: I have tested the code it is working well, make sure you are not making any mistake. Does your ajax-scripts.js file is accessible and have our ajax script? Please share your form HTML as well.

Comment: please explain me where each file should be.

Comment: i swear that i put the code exactly like you. but maybe in another location.

Comment: 1. Ajax Script in ajax-scripts.js file, and its location should be, themes->your_theme->js->ajax-scripts.js
2. Both php functions in your theme's functions.php file.